# How to call on a field from a new object

Tags: java, jgrasp

I created a class called "Person" here it is: (ignore the toString. I haven't done anything with that yet)

```
 public class Person {
    public String firstName;
    public String middleName;
    public String lastName;
    public Person() {
        firstName = "first";
        middleName = "middle";
        lastName = "last";
    }
    public Person(String first, String middle, String last) {
        firstName = first;
        middleName = middle;
        lastName = last;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return (firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName);
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

And then I created an implementation class in a new file, this is it:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestProgPerson
{

   static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      String first;
      String middle;
      String last;

      Person name = new Person("Joe", "Smith", "Blow");

      System.out.println("Name: " + name);

      System.out.println("Please enter a last name, to check if it corresponds with the persons last name: " );
      last = console.nextLine();

      if (last == (objectReference.lastName))
      System.out.println("The last name you entered matches the persons last name");
      else
      System.out.println("The last name you entered does not match the persons last name");

    }
}
```

So what I want it to do is this: Have an object with the first name, middle name, and last name. Output that name. (The program works this far). Then I want to have the user enter a last name, and the program checks to see if the entered last name is the same as the last name in the object. How do I go about calling just an individual string from that object?

Comment: I recommend using equals when comparing two string. In your case, just call the getLastName() method of the Person object and compare it to user's input

Comment: The variable `objectReference` appears to be defined nowhere in the code you pasted, but you want to be doing something like `if (last.equals(objectReference.getLastName( )))` rather than using the `==` operator.  This question is a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you Tim.. Solved my issues. Picking these little things is tough since I have only been coding for a few weeks. Sorry for asking a duplicate question, I didn't see an answer for what I was looking for. Must have over looked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are calling the name object of the class but not any field of that class.

```
System.out.println("Name: " + name);
```

You can call fields here by using the object of the class and the dot operator.

For Example.

```
System.out.println("Name: " + name.firstName + " " + name.middleName  + " " + name.lastName);
```

Moreover because strings are `Objects` and should be compared with the `equals` method.

Comment: + name calls the object, and prints the three strings ("Joe", "Smith", and "Blow"). I was just having issues with the if...else statement where I was trying to call upon just the last name ("Blow"). Got it figured out and working now though, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. We just need that your problem is solved.